# Fetch users list from 165 databases with 30 different DB schema using .NET CORE and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am building an API that will **fetch users list from 165 databases with 30 different DB schema**.

Some tables might have different names, like table `User`, it could be named `User`, `Users`, `AspNetUsers`, `ApplicationUser`.

Fields from certain tables might have different name even though they contain same information. like column `UserId`, it could be named `userId`, `user_id`, `uid`, `id` in different schema.

I want to get list of all users(C# Properties: `UserId`, `UserName`) from all databases, How can I reach this?

Currently, my app is only connected to one database with standard recommended configurations.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use EF for this? It seems like this will be a tricky problem for any ORM. Anyway it sounds like you need some kind of 'translation' layer which knows what table and column name to use for a particular database.

Comment: Perhaps this could be done better at the database level. If your database system [supports the concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) you could create a View for your many different tables and the select from that view

Comment: Write a script that will create code for you for all the 30 different databases. The created code will be unique to each db. Then use that code. In other words the script will figure out the field names, table names and write a select query for each one. Or just write the code for each db, 30 is not that much.

Comment: EF is the last tool to think of for this kind of job. Use Dapper.

Comment: One of the reasons why it's closed is that too much is unknown here. Like, is there some collection of connection strings? Is it known in advance which database has which schema or should the code sniff that out first? Is there a mixture of DB providers? Apparently it's not as simple as running one out of 30 prefabricated queries against each database. OP seems to look for something more advanced. Seeing a first effort would help in getting where OP is heading.

Answer (score 1):

To query "165 databases with 30 different DB schema", what you face first is **performance**. you need a revolutionary solution.

I had an experience to handle **super-heavy query** for a `distributed` application:

when we send a request to a API(Let's simply call it `GetUsersCount()`) , the API will simply send many sub-requests(it is "165" requests in your case) to other APIs with `parallel tasks`, then the API `GetUsersCount()` will `concat` all results to response. so the API `GetUsersCount()` doesn't do the any query, but `concat` results **only**. by this way, we reduced response time from 5-10 minutes to 1 seconds. so you need to add a `layer`(which should be another restful API) behind your API, which layer will **only** query one specific database with EF core.

But in your case, I wonder how big is your result? will you `sort/group/paging` result? but it can also be resolved by more detail designs with above idea.

But, if you have only several DBs(like, 2-3 DBs), I would suggest a [Cross-database-query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries?view=sql-server-ver15) to `union` all several tables to one view with a [Linked-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), and then use [Keyless-entity-type(Query-type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) to visibly operate result. 2 options:

1. Create the `view` to your current connected database with EF Core code-first approach, then visit the view as a table. follow the referenced posts, your will reach it.
2. Use `trigger`(if it's allowed) to synchnize the view-schame to one unique table of your connected database. this is the best when data is not huge and you have to `group, sort, paging` result.

Comment: Thanks all, I handled differences of the Databases on Databse layer and used Dapper instead of EF.